# Can I replace an AT28c17 with a CAT28c65B without changing my software?

Tags: atmel, eeprom

The AT28c17 is a 16k e2prom while the CAT28c65B is 64K bit e2prom and both are in a 32 pin PLLC package. They have 10 adresss lines with the only difference being the AT28c17 has
 A0-A10 adress lines  while the CAT28c65B has A0-A12.

The pin configrations of both are same but the pins 3 and 27 are NC on the AT28c17 while they are A12 (adress 12 pin) and A11 (adress 12 pin) on the CAT28c65B. Only these pins differ.

Can I replace the AT28c17 with a CAT28c65B without changing my software? Will it work?

Comment: You'll need a defined voltage on the pins that were NC and are address lines with the new part. Depending whether you choose high or low, the location in the part that will / needs to be programmed changes. I didn't check any other properties.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the AC write characteristics of the CAT28C65B are larger than that of the AT28C17 (100ns vs. 50 ns.); you may need to increase your delays when writing in order to compensate. Study the write cycle diagrams in both datasheets for full details.